# Is there a confirmed date for public beta?

Tags: support

Is there a confirmed date for public beta? I am just wondering, as I could not seem to find one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No**, but the earliest possible date is 7 Feb. When viewing the site without being logged in, you see:

[image: screenshot]

There's also a [general rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266555/278659) that all sites remain in private beta for at least 3 weeks, so **8 Feb** (three weeks after the launch on 18 Jan) seems the most likely date.

Comment: I appreciate this new three-week rule quite a bit.